# android listview fonts change dynamically

Tags: android

I am creating application where in i have used preferences for changing font settings.
I want to change the list view 's text through those preference values.
Have used check box preference for bold and italic.
and list preference for font size
How can i do this?
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ListView's adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv;
    if(convertView==null){
        tv=new TextView(...); //create new TextView
    }else tv=(TextView) convertView;

    //now here set your tv text, font etc.

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Tejaswini is using PreferencesActivity and that can't have an adapter, am I right?

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari, I'm not sure that he is, but if you're right I'll delete this post

Comment: I'm sure I think, because according to the android documetation, PrefernceActivities can just be populated with `addPreferencesFromResource(...)` method that gives a resource. So, I think uning an adapter will not be possibe.

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari, sorry, I meant "I'm not sure that he uses PreferencesActivity" :)

Comment: Sorry that was my fault. got it. I'm not so sure about that.